# Deal with Final Class With Static Method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, refactoring, mockito

I have a method, I want to test. In there I call a static method of a final Hybris-class (`Config.getParameter("aString")`). I want to mock it, but I found out, you can't do that with Mockito. So what would be a good way to approach this? The thing is, I am thinking about refactoring. But I can't change the Config-class, since it is from Hybris.

How can I change my class I want to test, so that I can influence the `Config.getParameter("aString")` call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1.Refactor your code and introduce ConfigWrapper (for example) interface:

```
public interface ConfigWrapper {
   public String getParameter(String parameter);

public class ConfigWrapperImpl implements ConfigWrapper{
   public String getParameter(String parameter){
      return Config.getParameter(parameter);
   }
}
```

Then you should refactor your code and replace Config.* usages by injecting ConfigWrapper. And when you write a test you can easily mock ConfigWrapper with mockito (cause you are using non-static method)

2. The second way is to use PowerMock instead of mockito:

   `PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)`

for more info u can see: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Comment: A better way, if a DI container/framework is going to be used, is to rely on it to inject the desired configuration parameter into an annotated `String` field. For example, something like `@Inject @Named("aString") String configParam`. This can be done with CDI, Spring, and Guice, although the details vary. The advantage is that it would simplify client code.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create an interface whose method (or methods) match what you expect from that `Config` class. Then you can do the following:

- create an implementation which uses that `Config` in production;
- create a mock for your tests.

A simplified example using Java 8:

```
// The interface
public interface MyInterface
{
    String getParameter(String paramName);
}

// Class using the interface
public final class MyClass
{
    private final MyInterface intf;

    // For testing...
    public MyClass(final MyInterface intf)
    {
        this.intf = Objects.requireNonNull(intf);
    }

    // In production...
    public MyClass()
    {
        this(Config::getParameter);
    }

    // etc
}

// Test class
@Test
public void whatever()
{
    final MyInterface intf = mock(MyInterface.class);
    // set up the mock, then...

    final MyClass myClass = new MyClass(intf);
    // test myClass
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use besides Mockito, a tool call [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) which can be helpful in your use case.